# PHP Settings [pm.max_children, pm.start_servers, pm.min_spare_servers and pm.max_spare_servers]

Tags: php, performance, error-handling, amazon-ec2

In the midst of transferring a website from a GoDaddy shared server to an EC2 instance. Handling the traffic, which during peak times on a typical day is around 300 active visitors, has been problematic to say the least.  My CPU usage slowly rises and eventually hits 100% leaving the website essentially unusable. I've been attempting to resolve the issues from my error logs and was wondering if there could be a more significant problem to address.

After looking at the Apache error log I increased MaxClients [prefork (256) / worker (300) / serverlimit (256)] ==> (500 / 500 / 500).

After looking at the PHP error log I increased [pm.max_children (50) / pm.start_servers (5) / pm.min_spare_servers (5) / pm.max_spare_servers (35)] ==> (100, 10, 10, 70)

Even with these numbers I continue to have warnings: 
[23-Feb-2014 04:34:47] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 7 idle, and 83 total children

Artificially increasing these numbers doesn't appear to be long term solution. Any ideas?

EC2:
[image: EC2]

RDS:
[image: RDS]

Comment: What control do you have over the server? Do you use MySQL? Have you checked CPU load? Can you post the performance stats that your control panel gives you? Have you checked memory? The more information you provide, the best answer you can get.

Comment: I have complete control over the server. I have a EC2 c1.medium instance for the web server and a m1.medium MySQL Database server. I have updated the post with the performance screen shots from my most recent test.

Answer (score 0):

- If your site doesn't use any kind of cache, start using one. There are many alternatives.
- Is the load coming from users? Reduce as much load from bots as you can. Establish rules to block IPs or agents.
- Use gzip if you can. It will pass some extra work to the CPU, but alleviates Apache.
- Avoid/prebent hotlinking. Remember, don't compress images or multimedia files, only text.
- Try setting [KeepAlive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#keepalive) Off. This will make users generate more connections and increases HTTP traffic and handshake, but relieves connections open. You are the only one that can find if you need it on or off.
- Reduce [keepalivetimeout](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout). You may prefer this instead of turning off [KeepAlive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#keepalive)
- Try to disable as many modules as you can. This may not be possible depending on the control you have over the server.

There is not much more that we can tell with out more details except generic things like, optimize your server side language pages, optimize database queries, etc.

**Update based on your graphs**

Assuming all the graphs have the same scale.

When your server hits 100% CPU, you have 0 reads and 0 writes, but you have a high network usage. Where is that traffic going/coming? You could think that is using the cache, but I'd be amazed that just cache can hold the whole access of users. I mean, they have to be using exactly the same files/pages without a single change. The problem with that, is not just how improbable is to have all the users hitting the same resource, is that you have some database access.

If the database is on the same server, the read/writes from the database are so low that they don't even raise the bar on the other graph. If the database is in another server, is normal that one doesn't affect the other.

But, the database is working, even when has almost no read/writes, is working, and the load is increasing, which points to problems with the queries. May be complex views, may be very inefficient queries, may be too much calculations on some queries. The queue depth seems to indicate that you have a bottle neck there.

I'd say that you have something making the database work really difficult, and that is what is affecting the most. If the database is in the same server. But it's not the whole story. Check that first.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have two different instances set up, one as a web sever and the other to handle the MySQL database. I have WordPress installed and have been playing around with the W3 Total Cache plugin in an effort to find the optimal configuration. At the moment I have page, browser and object caching enabled with APC. I have noticed that CPU spikes occur with 0 reads / writes, but what could be the cause of this?  The website is a picture based site that during peak hours can have 300+ active visitors.  I have analyzed the slow query logs, but no errors.

Comment: Did you check the queries? How does the server behaves if restarted? can you restart the server/servers? Try to debug the database first since that seems to be the problem. If you can deactivate the cache, do it while debugging.